# Erro: 'Operand type clash: image is incompatible with numeric'

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, calendar

Ao tentar salvar um objeto no banco, dá a seguinte exceção:

> org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not update. [...] Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Operand type clash: image is incompatible with numeric.

Eu peguei a *query* executada pelo Hibernate para fazer diretamente no banco. Coloquei nela os mesmos valores que estavam sendo dados no código. Apenas a data (que no código é atribuída com `Calendar.getInstance()`) eu não escrevi, colocando um `GETDATE()`. Funcionou! Se todos os campos eu escrevi igual, só a data que foi obtida de outro modo, creio que o problema está na data. Ainda mais pelo **'org.hibernate.exception.DataException'.**

Agora, não entendo o porquê. O tipo do campo no banco é `datetime`. No JPA, no código, está como `@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)`. O `Calendar.getInstance()` não deveria trazer problemas então.

Além disso, ainda tem essa do

> 'Operand type clash: image is incompatible with numeric'.

É como se ele estivesse acusando que coloquei algo do tipo imagem no objeto? Ainda por cima diz que é incompatível com numérico? Mas o campo é de data. E os outros campos devem estar ok, pois funcionou quando fiz a *query* com os mesmos valores direto no banco.

---

ATUALIZADO:

A query que é gerada pelo hibernate:

```sql
update TABELA 
set DATA_ALTERACAO_D= ?, 
LOGIN_USUARIO_T= ?, 
FK_TABELA2 = ?, 
IND_T= ?, 
LOGIN_USUARIO_ALT_T= ?, 
NUM_A = ?, 
NUM_U = ?, 
FK_TABELA2 = ?, 
S = ? 
where ID = ?
```

Eu coloquei a query diretamente no banco, com os mesmos valores que seriam recebidos colocados na query na aplicação, substituindo apenas a data (que na aplicação era `Calendar.getInstance()`) e coloquei o `GETDATE()` do SQL. 
ex:

```sql
update TABELA 
set DATA_ALTERACAO_D= GETDATE(), 
LOGIN_USUARIO_T= '8888888', 
FK_TABELA2 = '123123123123', 
IND_T= 'I', 
LOGIN_USUARIO_ALT_T= '8888888', 
NUM_A = '654654', 
NUM_U = '456456', 
FK_TABELA2 = '38383838', 
S = '1' 
where ID = '7777777777'
```

Aí funcionou.
Ou seja, o problema deve estar no campo de data. 
Mas não consigo entender como data se relaciona com esta mensagem de erro.

Comment: Duas coisas importantes: **1**. Tente usar títulos mais sucintos. **2**. Em **org.hibernate.exception.DataException** Data está em inglês, não tem nada a ver com data (tempo), mas isso não quer dizer que o problema esteja em outro campo. Tem como você colocar a *query* gerada pelo hibernate na pergunta?

Comment: Coloquei a query.

Comment: Realmente não entendo o problema. Já olhei, a depuração, os valores que ficam em todos os atributos do objeto e nenhum está recebendo algo do tipo image.

Answer (score 0):

parece que era por ser um campo que era fk (então eu não passava só o ID, passava o objeto todo pra esse campo fk) mas no jpa estava configurado como campo comum (@Column) e não como fk ( @JoinColumn). Por estar configurado como campo comum, ele esperava apenas um valor puro (acho que funcionaria se eu passasse só o id puro), mas eu passava um objeto inteiro, da qual ele deveria tirar o id e ele devia ficar sem entender. Aí só funcionaria se o campo estivesse configurado pra ser fk, com  @JoinColumn.

Troquei para  @JoinColumn e funcionou